# Visual Studio Cordova Hybrid App "release" vs "distribution"

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Please explain the difference between **Release** vs **Distribution** modes when running a hybrid app project from **Visual Studio for Apache Cordova**
In Visual Studio, in Solution Configurations drop-down you have:

- Debug
- Release
- Distribution

From what I can see "**release**" pushes the app to USB-connected Android device, while "distribution" only compiles it, and then just displays empty command prompt screen for adb.exe (but does not push the app to device).

I would like to test "distribution" version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only for iOS apps. Before being submitted to the App Store, iOS apps have to be signed by a Distribution Certificate. The distribution configuration uses this Distribution Certificate instead of a Development Certificate which is used for debug and release builds.

The distribution configuration seems to have been removed in the recently released RC, with release taking its place. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757048.aspx#iOS) which previously stated:

> When building a Debug or Release configuration, the Visual Studio remote agent selects the first valid iOS Development signing identity installed on your Mac.
>   When building a Distribution configuration, the Visual Studio remote agent selects the first valid iOS Distribution signing identity installed on your Mac.

now says:

> When building a Debug configuration, by default the Visual Studio remote agent selects the first valid iOS Development signing identity installed on your Mac.
>   When building a Release configuration, by default the Visual Studio remote agent selects the first valid iOS Distribution signing identity installed on your Mac.